# Is there a way to do a custom color remapping of everything shown on the screen in linux?

Tags: linux, colors, color-management

So I've developed this strange issue recently, which is that I feel headache-y when I read red text (though not for text of other colors, or for larger red objects). I was wondering if there was a way in linux to do arbitrary/custom color remappings, so for example I could remap all colors within some neighborhood of red #FF0000 to another color, eg blue.

I took an OS class in the past, so I have some level of comfort/familiarity with modifying the linux kernel / re-compiling it for myself, but I don't know where I would begin with something like this.

I was looking at f.lux and an open-source variant, and it seems like they just adjust the gamma levels, rather than doing a totally arbitrary/general color remapping.

Any thoughts for how I could go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is configured in your terminal's settings. At a minimum, it should allow you to change these colors:

**black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white**

These colors can be changed for both their 'normal' appearance and their 'bright' appearance (for example when bold text is shown).

If you install and run the command `neofetch`, its output will include two rows of colored blocks, the first row showing the 'normal' appearance, and the second showing the 'bright' appearance for each of the colors I listed above.

So depending on the terminal you're using, this setting may be adjusted through a config file or a GUI settings menu. In my case I'm using Alacritty, where the colors are changed through a yaml config file with the other settings.